# Unexpected Error while publishing - [NOSYMB (z\cvsay)]

Tags: flash, createjs, flash-cc

Does anybody know what [NOSYMB (z\cvsay)] error means while publishing Flash CreateJS document?

Comment: Which version of Flash are you using? Flash CC? Or is this an older version with the Toolkit panel?

Comment: Flash CC, but the problem was the symbol name (it contains some invalid characters).

Anyway gskinner, I am sure you will know something about this [problem](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1951500), which I thought was caused by this topics error.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the symbol names? I know Adobe was able to solve a bunch of issues with symbol names a couple versions back, but it sounds like there may be some left. I'd be happy to pass it on to them.

Comment: In this case the symbol name was "z\cvsay". My only guess is that Flash CC messed Polish name after importing project from CS6. Chaning symbol name so it does not contains "\" helps.